# Access: User inputs years to query dates in that fiscal year

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I want to enter the fiscal year (18/19) and have the query only select from dates within that range. The year is March 1 - Feb 28/29. Is there a way to enter the string "18/19" or "21/22" and have those dates separated apart and turned into the parameter/criteria? I am not proficient at SQL, but this is roughly what I have in mind.

```
WHERE ([Combined All].Date_Read)>= #3/1/Left([Water Year:],2)# 
  And ([Combined All].Date_Read)<=#2/1/Right([Water Year:],2)#;
```

Alternatively, I though of creating a string with the date and entering that into the WHERE, but I'm lost on how to do that

```
strYearOne = "03/01/" & left([Water Year:],2)
strYearTwo = "03/01/" & right([Water Year:],2)
```

I'm not very familiar with SWL/Access syntax and I'm sure I'm mixing everything up. TIA

Comment: Your first suggestion should work. Why didn't you try? The second operates with "text" dates which should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [`DateSerial`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dateserial-function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503) to build date in year, month, and day parts:

```sql
WHERE ([Combined All].Date_Read) >= DateSerial([StartYear], 3, 1)
  AND ([Combined All].Date_Read) <  DateSerial([EndYear], 3, 1);
```

When above is run in MS Access (i.e., .exe application), the user will be prompted for these two parameters. However, query will fail if running MS Access as a backend (i.e., ODBC connection) where you will need to supply these parameters such as binding to qmark placeholders as used in Python ODBC, PHP ODBC, and VBA ADO:

```sql
WHERE ([Combined All].Date_Read) >= DateSerial(?, 3, 1)
  AND ([Combined All].Date_Read) <  DateSerial(?, 3, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on DateSerial, it worked perfectly. I also updated it so I only have to enter 1 input:  `WHERE ([Combined All].Date_Read) >= DateSerial(left([FiscalYear],2), 3, 1)
 AND ([Combined All].Date_Read) <  DateSerial(right([FiscalYear],2), 3, 1);`  Now I just enter 18/19 and it uses the left and right half in one entry.

Comment: Great to hear. You can also enter a single year and have the later year expressed as `[FiscalYear] + 1`!